# How to exclude aidl files using soourceSets

Tags: android

I have tried everything I can think of, but nothing has worked. If you know where I am wrong, please let me know. Thank you

```
packagingOptions{
   // not working
   exclude 'com/demo/aidl/IDemo.class'
}

sourceSets{
    // not working
    main.aidl.exclude 'com/demo/aidl/IDemo.java'
    // not working
    main.aidl.exclude 'com/demo/aidl/IDemo.aidl'
    // not working
    main.java.exclude 'com/demo/aidl/IDemo.java'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I have to do it another way

```
1. move the aidl file to module B
2. compilyOnly module B
```